# Laravel Many to Many Relationship ( hasMany or belongsToMany )

Tags: php, laravel, model, many-to-many, relationship

I am currently building my first App with Laravel and have stumbled upon the problem that I dont know how to setup the relationship Many-to-Many between the Models (User and Group).

I've created a board in which I store the relationship between all users and the Group they are in.
My Problem is that I dont know how to acces and set this up in Laravel.
Im not sure whether I have to user hasMany or belongsToMany.

I am trying to find a method to add a User to Group, so that a new entry will be created in the UserGroups table.

My tables:

User

- ID
- Name
- Email

Group

- ID
- Name
- Creator_ID

UserGroup

- User_ID
- Group_ID

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a many-to-many relationship, it should be `belongsToMany`, not `hasMany`.

In the `Group` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

And in the `User` model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

The pivot table should be called `group_user`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

In the model class, use belongsToMany as demonstrated here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

To add a user to a group, use attach(), as demonstrated here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method (scroll to many to many relations)